How to Fix H1 tag Largest Contentful Paint (LCP) Issue in Angular App as Reported by Lighthouse?
I am working on an Angular application, and Lighthouse is reporting a very high Largest Contentful Paint (LCP) time for my app. Here are the details:
LCP Element:
<h1 class="maintitle_withicon" style="font-size: 32px; font-weight: 700; color: #333;">
  home Welcome back, Case Worker30
</h1>

LCP Time: 23,150 ms

Description: The  tag contains the text "Welcome back, Case Worker30", and Lighthouse identifies it as the LCP element. I’ve already adjusted its CSS properties (e.g., optimized font size, weight, and color) to simplify rendering.
Steps Taken
Font Optimization:
Added font-display: swap to all @font-face rules.
Preloaded critical fonts used in the  tag.
CSS Optimization:
Reduced visual complexity (e.g., no heavy shadows).
Verified that the styles render efficiently across browsers.
Lazy Loading:
Issues
Despite the above optimizations, the LCP time remains excessively high.
Questions

How can I optimize it?
Are there tools or techniques in the Angular ecosystem to debug and improve LCP performance?
Is there a better way to optimize the  tag's CSS or rendering to reduce LCP time effectively?
Any insights, tips, or best practices would be greatly appreciated! Let me know if additional details are needed.


23 seconds sounds like a huge LCP! There really isn't enough information here but I would guess that's how long it's taking your app to launch and hydrate and the user is looking at a spinner until then? If so then there's nothing you can do to that element but you need to either 1) display the text without hydration with server-side rendering, and/or 2) reduce the hydration time.

Thank you for your input! You're absolutely right—23 seconds is a significant LCP time. Currently, the app displays a spinner during the loading phase, and the LCP element is only rendered after hydration completes. Your suggestions are very helpful, and I’ll certainly explore them further:
Reducing Hydration Time: Given the number of API calls running in the background to fetch CMS details, reducing hydration time is a complex challenge. While we have been working on optimizing resources and minimizing render-blocking elements, it hasn’t yet resulted in significant improvements.

Please let me know what are the details you need will try to share

I think it’s worth restating what LCP is: this Web Vital measures the largest element rendered on the screen before user interaction. Given that you are running the Lighthouse test, it reports the largest component of the viewport—which happens to be the H1 tag. However, it may not be a problem with the element itself but rather with the preceding application loading steps.
To better understand the flow, I would suggest measuring (and sharing here) TTFB and Element Render Delay. Resource load delay and duration should be zero since it’s a text element.
I would expect that Element Render Delay will be bigger than TTFB; thus, to optimize LCP, you would need to focus on that.
The best way to improve it would be to debug which steps are happening before the H1 element shows up. Those might include:
•   Loading application code
•   Fetching data through API

If that’s the case, consider:
•   Splitting application code into chunks, loading the part that’s needed to render the initial UI first
•   Using pagination or decreasing server latency to speed up data load

Please share the performance report from the developer tools; we might be able to provide more specific recommendations.
Also, I would recommend reading this article: https://web.dev/blog/common-misconceptions-lcp

Thank you for clarifying the nuances of LCP and for your detailed suggestions—it’s incredibly helpful. Here’s some additional context and Thank you for sharing the article from web.dev. I’ll review it to ensure we’re fully aligned with best practices for optimizing LCP.
Your suggestions give us a clear path forward, and we truly appreciate your expertise. I’ll share the performance report shortly to get your further input.
